# What is the limit number of operations currently in NSOperationQueue queue

Tags: ios, nsoperation

I cannot find any documents that mention "What is the limit number of operations currently in NSOperationQueue queue?"

Can my queue still work if it has 1000 Facebook-graph-request operations?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean held on the queue, or executing at the same time?

Comment: Hi jrturton, I mean held on the queue not executing at the same time

Answer (score 4):

There is no API-enforced limit to the number of operations you can add to a queue, any more than there is a limit to the number of objects you can add to an NSArray.

Any limitations are those imposed by the device, notably the available memory. If you are adding so many operations you run out of memory to hold them, let alone execute them, you're doing it wrong.